# canvas.drawImage behaves differently if the source is an image or if it is a offscreen context

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, html5-canvas

I am blitting an image to a context using several drawimage to get a non-linear interpolation on y axis.
Here is a very simplified version of my code.

```
var destY = 0;
for (i=0; i<16; i++)
{
   context.drawImage(pictureToBlit, 
                 0, i, 16, 1,
                 0,destY,512,i*3);
   destY+=i*3;
}
```

This code produces the expected bilinear interpolation looking on all browsers when pictureToBlit is an image coming from the DOM.

See this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TeckelCruel/w72wkta4/8/)

But when pictureToBlit is an offscreen context (a CanvasRenderingContext2D) then the result becomes different on latest version of Chrome 40.0.2214.94 m :

See the same [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TeckelCruel/w72wkta4/8/) and replace if (true) by if (false)

**Why is the image drawing behaving differently when source is an image or a offscreen canvas containing the same image?**

Comment: It seems very much like a Chrome bug. You could check if it's here already, file it otherwise.

Comment: Good idea I posted a bug in Chromium: #454542